# Buscar valores com parte de texto

Tags: microsoft-excel, funções

Estou com um seguinte problema, tenho uma [planilha](https://www.sendspace.com/file/6tjgsy). Atualmente consigo fazer a pesquisa por nome, porém eu queria digitar apenas parte do nome, por exemplo, ao invés de digitar "Raquel", digito "Ra" ele já me trazer Raquel, Rafael, Raimundo, etc...

Com esta fórmula `=PROCV("*"&B8&"*";B11:F100;2;FALSO)`, por exemplo, eu consigo pegar parte do texto.

O que preciso, e não estou conseguindo, é unir as duas funções.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Em outro fórum conseguiram entender minha dúvida...caso alguém tenha entendido e se interessou em descobrir a solução, segue a fórmula: =SE($G$5="";"";SE(LINS($H$5:$H5)>CONT.SE($A$5:$A$15;"*"&$G$5&"*");"";ÍNDICE($B$5:$B$15;MENOR(SE(NÃO(ÉERROS(LOCALIZAR("*"&$G$5&"*";$A$5:$A$15)));LIN($B$5:$B$15)-LIN($B$4));LINS($H$5:$H5))))) (aperte CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER para fazer matricial)